# How do I get only one value for the data I fetched from database using fetch function

Tags: php, jquery, pdo

I am new to php and had chosen to stick to PDO format. I have been able to set up a workable registration and login system, but my challenge is fetching data from my database which would be used in other page of the user profile page I created. I had tried all the many examples and methods I was able to get on the internet but there are not working, or rather I don't know how to use it, where I want to insert the variable will still be empty.
The only fetch function I was able to get will select all the row, for instance, if it is email, it will fetch all the registered emails in the database which is not suppose to be. The email should only be for the user whose profile is opened.
Here are the codes. I am sure someone will help me figure this out. Thanks

```
    $data = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM databaseName")->fetchAll();
    //this one is in the body where i want to insert the email
    foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo $row['email']."<br />\n";
}
```

I tried everything my little knowledge of php but all to no avail. If i decide to use any other one, nothing will show.

Comment: What do you mean by "get only one value"? The given query is able to select multiple rows, and if you need only one of them, you have to write some code for that filter

Comment: "By one value, I mean if it is the email I want, it should be only one email which is associated with that user, not the whole email in my database. Thank

Comment: Well, then add some filter. There is no way we can guess from the given code how your user system works

Answer (score 0):

You can try other alternative to achieve the same,

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM databasetable');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    echo $row['email'] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried it but it is still giving me thesame problem. When I did it, it fetched all the emails in the database. But what I want is only one email associated with the user whose dashboard is opened. Any thanks

Comment: `$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM databasetable where email like '".$yourEmail."'");` one record associated with email

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the email from the returned results, I would look to do the following:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT `email` FROM databasetable');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row['email'] . "\n";
}
```

Or

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT `email` FROM databasetable');
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))

foreach($data as $row)
{
    echo $row['email'] . "\n";
}
```

If you want to check that the data coming back is good, I would add a "`print_r($data);`".

Comment: I am having another issue after I used the codes above. I don't know what i am not getting right. When I login any user, it will redirect to only one user. For instance, when i login any user, it will redirect to 'greeser' (a username in the database). Any other login attempt, it will still redirect to 'greeser'. I don't know how to solve this. Can somebody help me.

Comment: In the query comment, you'll need a WHERE clause. 

// select a particular user by id
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=:id");
$stmt->execute(['id' => $id]); 
$user = $stmt->fetch();

Answer (score 0):

You can just take the first element of the results.

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT `email` FROM databasetable LIMIT 1');
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)[0];
```

or use `fetch()`

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT `email` FROM databasetable LIMIT 1');
$data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I´ve also put a LIMIT at the end of your query, so you dont fetch unneeded data.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, they all worked fine for me. I am glad am a part of this great community

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something then surely you should be specifying a where in your SQL query, why would you get the entire database and loop through it until you find the email you want?

When you redirect the logged in user you must(or if you aren't then you should) be passing something about the user, e.g setting the userid in the session.  Then you can use this to create more useful profile data with a query that says `select email from table where userid = :userid` - then when you fetch the result you will have the data you need.

Naturally I can't write the exact query without knowing your structure but getting a whole tables worth of data every time is unscalable

Comment: Thanks jameson2012. I am really new to php so please pardon my basic questions. Please you talked about structure  (' I can't write the exact query without knowing your structure'). I don't know what you mean by structure, is it framework like bootstrap or something.

Comment: I mean your database structure, what tables you have what the links between them are etc I just mean you'd have to decide what information you needed for the WHERE clause in your sql